# ASP .Net Passing value from gridview using Session State (VB)

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am classic asp programmer that is learning .net.  Here is my problem:

I have a gridview with the following columns: Pkey, Name, Address.  Lets say that I want to have a hyperlink on the Pkey field to pass that value to another page.  I have been able to get this to work using querystrings.  I would like to use session state to do this.  I really don’t have any idea how to do this since the pkey is in the gridview.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to?  Setting a session variable is going to require a postback and then a redirection to the other page, where a query string parameter goes straight to the other page without a roundtrip to the server.  The query string in the hyperlink will also work correctly if the user has multiple windows/tabs open to the same page containing the gridview; if tab 1 sets the session variable to X and tab 2 sets the session variable to Y, isn't the application going to get confused?

Comment: Since I am in still learning .net, I just thought session state was the new to pass a variable to another page instead of using the querystring.  So this is still the preferred method to pass the variables then?

Comment: I would prefer the QueryString, but @pjabbott: there would not be an _extra_ roundtrip, just a slightly longer one. It can be a useful technique.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :
First Page

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var firstCell = e.Row.Cells[0];
            firstCell.Controls.Clear();
            firstCell.Controls.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = "secondpage?pkey = " + firstCell.Text, Text = firstCell.Text, Target = "_blank" });
            Session["PKEY"] = firstCell.Text;
        }
    }
Second Page :

```
    string pkey = Convert.ToString(Session["PKEY"]);
    label1.Text = pkey;
```